# Reset a Hyperlink In Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink

So when you click a hyperlink in Excel, the font goes from Blue to purple,

How does Excel know when a link has been clicked ?

And secondly, how can i reset it so that it returns back to blue
(without saving and closing etc.)

[image]

My hyperlinks are made using the formula' like below:

```
=HYPERLINK("http://api.wunderground.com/api/eec4c24fa3e74d09/history_20171110/q/"&F675&"/"&C675&".json")
```

This allows them to be dynamic, but once it is clicked it stays purple even if i change the values in `F675` or `C675`

Comment: One way could be using VBA, save the formula in a variable, clear the contents of the cell and rebuild the formula in the same cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from comment from @pat2015

I used VBA to reset each Hyperlink:

```
Sub ResetHyper()

'   Select HyperLinks
    Range("H2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

'   Clear Current HyperLink
    Selection.ClearContents

'   Rebuild HyperLink
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=HYPERLINK(""http://api.wunderground.com/api/eec4c24fa3e74d09/history_20171110/q/""&RC[-2]&""/""&RC[-5]&"".json"")"

'   Select and Copy Down
    Range("H2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H750")
    Range("H2:H750").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This will "reset" each cell containing a hyperlink *(formula type hyperlink)*:

```
Sub HyperResetter()
    Dim r As Range, f As String

    For Each r In Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        f = r.Formula
        If InStr(1, f, "=HYPERLINK") > 0 Then
            r.Clear
            r.Formula = f
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

The text color will be fixed, but other special formatting will also be reset.

Answer (score 0):

This resets hyperlink worksheet formulas and hyperlinks to individual cells for the active worksheet. The first loop looks for hyperlinks in spreadsheet formulas. Deleting the formula and rewriting it resets followed links to unfollowed. The second loop looks for linked cells. It resets the hyperlink by getting the cell and address and relinking them. The original link does not need to be deleted. The text to display does not need to be included for this to work, and Excel 365 seemed to have a problem getting it anyway. The "If rngCell.HasFormula = False Then" had something I removed that was unrelated to hyperlinks. I left it because "If rngCell.HasFormula and InStr(rngCell.Formula, "HYPERLINK") > 0" is effectively a nested if and this way just seemed neater to me.

```
'2020-01-30
'reset all hyperlinks to unfollowed in active sheet
Sub fResetHyperlinks()
Dim hypLink As Hyperlink
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim strFormula As String
Dim strAddress As String
Dim strSubAddress As String
    For Each rngCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If rngCell.HasFormula = False Then  'look for formulas
        ElseIf InStr(rngCell.Formula, "HYPERLINK") > 0 Then 'containing hyperlinks
            strFormula = rngCell.Formula    'remember hyperlink formula
            rngCell.Clear   'erase hyperlink
            rngCell.Formula = strFormula    'recreate
        End If
    Next
    For Each hypLink In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks  'look for hyperlinked cells
        Set rngCell = hypLink.Range 'get cell
        strAddress = hypLink.Address    'get addresses
        strSubAddress = hypLink.SubAddress
        If strSubAddress = "" Then  'can't use subaddress if empty
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngCell, Address:=strAddress
        Else    'doesn't want or need display text
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngCell, Address:=strAddress, SubAddress:=strSubAddress
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I know the other answers here don’t provide a good example, but we prefer answers to include some explanation and not just code. Can you explain how your answer is different from the others? Why do you say “If (condition is False) Then (do nothing) Else…” instead of just testing whether the condition is true? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.